# Java: reading variable-size packets using NIO

Tags: java, networking, nio

I am writing the server component of an application that I am working on. I am using NIO to handle the networking, but I am struggling to figure out an efficient way to handle reading. The client application can send packets to the server that vary greatly in size. It could be a 100 byte text message, or a 500 kilobyte picture, and the server needs to be capable of handling those packets. Usually, I would create a buffer that is big enough to contain the largest possible packet, but in the case of this application, that would mean that I may have to have buffers *megabytes* in size for each client, and that would devour memory. After a discussion with my friend, I have decided that I want to handle this a bit like how I would if I was using old IO. This means that I would allocate a new buffer for every packet, the buffer having the capacity exactly the length of the incoming packet. My packet structure is as follows:

[int] [length]
[byte] [opcode]
[byte...] [payload]

My approach is to have two separate buffers: one buffer with a capacity of 4 to read the length, and another buffer which will be constantly re-initialized with a different capacity - the length of the packet. Here is the code that I came up with:

```
User user = (User) selectionKey.attachment();
SocketChannel socketChannel = user.getSocketChannel();
ByteBuffer readBuffer = user.getReadBuffer();
ByteBuffer lengthBuffer = user.getLengthBuffer();
/*
 * Read as many packets as possible.
 */
while (true) {
    /*
     * Read the length if it has not been read yet.
     */
    if (lengthBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
    socketChannel.read(lengthBuffer);
    /*
     * If the length could not be read, stop reading and wait for
     * more data to arrive.
     */
    if (lengthBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
        break;
    }
    } else {
    /*
     * Create a read buffer if one has not been created for the
     * incoming packet.
     */
    if (readBuffer == null) {
        lengthBuffer.flip();
        user.setReadBuffer(ByteBuffer.allocate(lengthBuffer
            .getInt()));
    }
    /*
     * Attempt to read the packet.
     */
    socketChannel.read(readBuffer);
    /*
     * If the packet was not completely read, then stop reading
     * altogether because all of the data has not been received yet.
     */
    if (readBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
        break;
    } else {
        /*
         * Otherwise, handle the data and prepare the buffers for
         * the next packet read.
         */
        readBuffer.flip();
        user.handleData();
        user.setReadBuffer(null);
        lengthBuffer.clear();
    }
    }
}
```

And there are a couple of problems that I see with this. For one, I sometimes get a NullPointerException on the line `socketChannel.read(readBuffer)`. Along with that, this solution does not seem clean. I feel that there is too much logic in the code and it seems problematic. Could anybody provide me with some modifications or my code or a different approach altogether? I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

On a side note, could anyone post in the comments a nice way to paste code from Eclipse into here and format it properly? I use the code button but the indentation is still incorrect, as you probably noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use netty framework. As it has already mechanism to handle these kind of problems. Have a look at [this](http://netty.io/4.0/guide/#start.pojo)

Comment: Hmm... I do think it would save me some time using a library.

Answer (score -1):

You need to view the connection as a byte stream. There is no such thing as a packet in TCP. The server might send you 100 bytes then 500 bytes but it could arrive at the receiver all together, one byte at a time, or anything in between. So if you have distinct messages in your protocol the first requirement is that you be able to split them up yourself, as though you were reading them from a file instead of a socket. Until you've built that into your protocol the problem is insoluble.

Comment: I do structure all of my packets in the same manner. I know that once I read the length I need to read length amount of bytes. Once that is read I know that the next 4 bytes read will be another length and so forth. The problem that I am having is actually writing efficient and effective code to go through that process.